# Converting models from QGIS to Python scripts?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, sextante

I want to automate some tools for QGIS 2.0.2 using Python.

Previously I have used ArcMap for automating tools and now i want to use QGIS.

In ArcMap I used the ModelBuilder, and more specifically the command Export to Python Script to generate Python code from my model.

Now I want to find something similar that will do the same job for my QGIS model
i.e. I want to export my model in QGIS to a Python script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Save as Python script`

[image]

The result is a script that you can use in the Toolbox or in the Python console

```
##Extract raster values (shapefile)=name
##vectorlayer_inputvector=vector
##rasterlayer_inputraster=raster
##boolean_reprojectvectortorastercrs=boolean false
##output_layer_alg1=output vector
outputs_0=processing.runalg("script:pointsfromvector", rasterlayer_inputraster, vectorlayer_inputvector, None)
outputs_1=processing.runalg("script:extractrastervaluestoshapefile", rasterlayer_inputraster, outputs_0['Output_layer'], boolean_reprojectvectortorastercrs, output_layer_alg1)
```

[image]

Comment: can i save there my model ?

Comment: The model is saved with the Python script

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work in 2,6 or 2,8. Does anyone know an alternative method?

Comment: @HCHaase - I can confirm that for Windows, QGIS 2.6.1 does still have this function.

Comment: @HCHaase If you find this does not work at 2.6 and/or 2.8 it would seem like a new question related to that may be needed.

Comment: @Joseph. hmm.. this might be related to the the version of the processing plugin. can you please check your version number? with processing v 2.6 and 2.9 this option is not available for me (in QGIS 2.6).

Comment: @HCHaase - My apologies, you are absolutely correct. I haven't updated my Processing plugin from v2.2. Those options do not appear for the versions you mentioned. Could you not downgrade to v2.2 or are there particular tools you use which are only availabe in the later processing versions?

Comment: @Joseph - Thanks. I definitely think downgrading would be the solution.

Comment: The save as python was removed when Modeller was rebuilt using a better system. It's planned to make a comeback in future according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121537/export-model-to-python-script-in-qgis-2-6, but that hasn't happened yet.