# Exporting model to Python script in QGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2, model

Where has the export model to Python script option gone in QGIS 2.6.0?

Comment: If you right-click on the model from **Processing Toolbox**, there should be an option to _Save as Python script_.

Comment: Yes, this did work in the previous QGIS package I used Version 2.0.1, but the option is missing from the right click menu in 2.6

Comment: Weird, I am also using 2.6 and the option is still available for me. Have you tried disabling the **Processing** plugin, restart QGIS and enable the plugin again?

Comment: Tried that but no change. I will reinstall and see if that helps. I have also see the problem documented here:http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/34664

Comment: What platform are you using (Windows, Linux)? Perhaps it could be a bug.

Comment: Tried the reinstall with no luck. I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit OS. What are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. Hopefully other users of Windows 8.1 can confirm if they can see this option.

Answer (score 7):

The "export to Python" option in the modeler has been taken out in the latest version. The modeler has been rewritten and there was not enough time to implement this feature. We have released the new version without it, considering that the improvements that this new modeler have are really worth it. The "export to Python" version will be available again in future releases

If you are still seeing that option, it means that QGIS is not picking the latest version correctly and is loading an older version of Processing. Removing the [home]/.qgis2/python/plugins/Processing folder (in case it exists) might help, since it will remove any other version of Processing that was installed using the plugin manager.

Comment: Does anyone know when this will be added again? QGIS 2.8 doesn't seem to have it. Is this even planned for future releases?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is available again in the 3.6 release.
The release notes are documented here: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog36/index.html#feature-resurrected-model-to-python-script-functionality