# How to add a value to a raster in QGIS 2.2 modeler?

Tags: qgis-2, qgis-modeler

I want to add a plain floating point value as a user input (model input) to a raster.

For example, I want to calculate +4.3 to each cell of the raster.
I remember this can easily be done in ArcGIS using (I think it's called) MathAlgebra.

In QGIS, I cannot find how to achieve it. The raster calculator algorithm doesn't let me reference a single numerical input as can be seen from the screenshot.

[image]

Are there other algorithms I can use?
I read in some [qgis manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_hydro_calculator.html), that you should be able to reference variables from previous calculation outputs, but I have no idea how to do this with a single numerical value.

I use QGIS-2.2.0 Valmiera.

**UPDATE:**

I updated to 2.8.2 and there is an option, that was also available in 2.2., which is described in the Calculator tool. You can refer to model values by referencing a variable.

[image]

I entered `+a->float value` in the formula field of my Raster calculator step. I am not sure if I got the point how to use it correctly.

I couldn't yet verify because of some error (might be a different problem with my model) the model did not run correctly.

Comment: Is there any reason not to update to 2.8.2 and try again?

Comment: No one that would prevent me from giving it a try. But [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121537/export-model-to-python-script-in-qgis-2-6) could be a serious one, once the model is finished.

Comment: Updated my question after upgrading to 2.8.2.